# Performance bottlenecks when using async-await with Azure Storage API

Tags: azure, async-await, task, azure-storage, threadpool

I'm hitting a performance bottleneck, on insertion requests using the Azure Table Storage API. I'm trying to reach of a speed of at least 1 insert per 30ms into a table (unique partition keys).

What is the recommended way to achieve this request rate and how can I fix my program to overcome my bottleneck?

I have a test programs that inserts into the azure table at roughly 1 / 30ms. With this test program, the latency continuously increases and requests begin to take even more than 15 seconds per insert.

Below is the code for my test program. It creates async tasks that log the time it takes to `await` on the `CloudTable` `ExecuteAsync` method. Unfortunately, the insertion latency just grows as the program runs.

```
List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
while (true)
{
    Thread.Sleep(30);
    tasks = tasks.Where(t => t.IsCompleted == false).ToList(); // Remove completed tasks
    DynamicTableEntity dte = new DynamicTableEntity() { PartitionKey = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), RowKey = "abcd" };
    tasks.Add(AddEntityToTableAsync(dte));
}

...

public static async Task<int> AddEntityToTableAsync<T>(T entity) where T : class, ITableEntity
{
    Stopwatch timer = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    var tableResult = await this.cloudTable.ExecuteAsync(TableOperation.InsertOrReplace(entity));
    timer.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine($"Table Insert Time: {timer.ElapsedMilliseconds}, Inserted {entity.PartitionKey}");

    return tableResult.HttpStatusCode;
}
```

I thought that it might be my test program running out of threads for the outgoing Network IO, so I tried monitoring the available thread counts during the program's execution:

```
ThreadPool.GetAvailableThreads(out workerThreads, out completionIoPortThreads);
```

It showed that nearly all the IO threads were available during execution (Just in case, I even tried increasing the available threads but that had no affect on the issue).

As I understand it, for async tasks, the completion port threads don't get "reserved" until there's data on them to process, so I started thinking that there might be an issue with my connection to Azure Table Storage.

However, I confirmed that was not the case by lowering the request rate (1 insert / 100ms) and launching 30 instances of my test program on the same machine. With 30 instances, I was able to maintain a stable ~90ms / insert without any increase in latency.

What can I do to enable a single test program to achieve a simillar performance that I was getting when running 30 programs on the same machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The test program was hitting the `System.Net.ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit`. The default value is 2

Increasing the number to 100 fixes the problem. And allows the single program to achieve the same speed as the 30 programs scenario